# How to find multiple present elements and display them in Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

What I want to accomplish in Selenium using Python is to be able to check multiple elements to see if they are present. I then want to display a message of "present" if they are present, then a message of "not present" when they aren't on the page being tested. I also want the test to register a message prior to testing that grabs the title of the page and enters it into a print statement to read out something like "Testing Test Page." I don't know the best way to go about this.

Is there somehow I can enter my code without it being endless lines of setting a variable to the tag/class name of the element I want to check, plus the if/else statements to go with them?

Below is the code I've managed to get working, but it's not as perfect as I want it.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

   def setUp(self):
   self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

   # What is being tested
   def test_search(self):
   driver = self.driver
   driver.get("localhost:8888/")
   self.assertIn("localhost:8888/", driver.title)
   if driver.title == "http://localhost:8888/":
       print("Testing Test Page...")
   else:
       print("Pages don't match up. Please check the code.")

   elem = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("body")

   if len(elem):
       print(elem.tag_name)
   else:
       print(elem.tag_name, " is not present")

   # Clean up testing
   def tearDown(self):
   self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
 unittest.main()
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need a `for` loop

Comment: @tegancp I wouldn't know where to start for that.